# Cast BigDecimal to Short in Freemarker

Tags: java, casting, freemarker, bigdecimal

I have a `Map<Short, String>` in my freemarker value-stack and I need to print a value in the template in this way:

```
${map.get(3)}
```

Since freemarker interprets that `3` as a BigDecimal an exception is thrown:

```
freemarker.core._TemplateModelException:[...]
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Short cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
    at java.math.BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.java:220)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:352)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:278)
```

Of course I can make the String value accessible in the value stack, but is there a more elegant way to cast numbers to `Short` in freemarker?

(I'm using `freemarker 2.3.25`)

Comment: Try ${map.get(new java.math.BigInteger("3").shortValue())}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `${map.get(3?short)}`.

This is a problem with calling API-s that don't declare the type of their parameter (such as `Map.get(Object)`; the generic type parameter is erased during compilation).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
${map.get(new java.math.BigInteger("3").shortValueExact())}

OR

${map.get(new java.math.BigInteger("3").shortValue())}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, not even the mere `${new java.math.BigInteger("3").shortValueExact()}` or `${new java.math.BigInteger("3").shortValue()}`, I've got a `freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template [...] :
Encountered "java"`